# Alternative to a lot of if statements jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to validate my form using jquery before submission. The user needs to fill up the **Task** accordingly, they cannot submit the form with fill-up **Task 2** and missing **Task 1**. And also the **Task** cannot be duplicated with other **Task**. I'm wondering if there any better way to compare all of this, in a simple method.

[image]

The Javascript currently I'm doing. Still not complete yet because looking for better ways.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#create_model" ).submit(function( event ) {
        if(validate_task()){
            alert("Check your task.");
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            $("#create_model").submit();
        }
    });
});

function validate_task() {
    if ($('#CatTask2ID').val() !== "" &&  $('#CatTask2ID').val() === "") {
        return "Task 1 is empty"; //return FALSE;
    } else if ($('#CatTask3ID').val() !== "" &&  $('#CatTask1ID').val() === "" || $('#CatTask2ID').val() === "")  {
        return "Task 1 or 2 is empty"; //return FALSE;
    } else if ($('#CatTask4ID').val() !== "" &&  $('#CatTask1ID').val() === "" || $('#CatTask2ID').val() === "" || $('#CatTask3ID').val() === "")  {
        return "Task 1, 2 or 3 is empty"; //return FALSE;
    } else if ($('#CatTask5ID').val() !== "" &&  $('#CatTask1ID').val() === "" || $('#CatTask2ID').val() === "" || $('#CatTask3ID').val() === "" || $('#CatTask4ID').val() === "")   {
        return "Task 1, 2 or 3 is empty"; //return FALSE;
    } else if ($('#CatTask5ID').val() !== "" &&  $('#CatTask1ID').val() === "" || $('#CatTask2ID').val() === "" || $('#CatTask3ID').val() === "" || $('#CatTask4ID').val() === "")   {
        return "Task 1, 2 or 3 is empty"; //return FALSE;
    } else if ($('#CatTask1ID').val() === $('#CatTask2ID').val() || $('#CatTask1ID').val() === $('#CatTask3ID').val()  .......and others...........  )    {
        return "Duplicates"; //return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd probably just suggest a switch statement

Comment: Visitors, Decorators, and Chain of Responsibility design patters can be used for this. Although I'd just suggest a validation library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use classes instead of IDs so you can get a collection of all selects easily, then map each select to its value to get an array of values.

Find the index of the first value which is the empty string. If any values *after* that one are populated, return an error saying that the index of that empty string is empty.

Otherwise, take the populated values (from indices 0 to the index of the first empty string), and check if the size of a Set of those values is equal to the length of the array:

```
function validate_task() {
  const taskValues = [...$('.tasks')].map(task => task.value);
  const firstEmptyIndex = taskValues.indexOf('');
  if (firstEmptyIndex > 0 && taskValues.slice(firstEmptyIndex).some(val => val)) {
    return `Task ${firstEmptyIndex + 1} is empty`;
  }
  const populatedTasks = taskValues.slice(0, firstEmptyIndex);
  if (populatedTasks.length !== new Set(populatedTasks).size) {
    return 'Duplicates';
  }
  // OK
}
```

Live demo:

```js
document.addEventListener('change', () => console.log(validateTask()));

function validateTask() {
  const taskValues = [...$('.tasks')].map(task => task.value);
  const firstEmptyIndex = taskValues.indexOf('');
  if (firstEmptyIndex !== -1 && taskValues.slice(firstEmptyIndex).some(val => val)) {
    return `Task ${firstEmptyIndex + 1} is empty`;
  }
  const populatedTasks = taskValues.slice(0, firstEmptyIndex);
  if (populatedTasks.length !== new Set(populatedTasks).size) {
    return 'Duplicates';
  }
  return 'OK'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="tasks">
  <option></option>
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
  <option>baz</option>
  <option>buzz</option>
</select>
<select class="tasks">
  <option></option>
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
  <option>baz</option>
  <option>buzz</option>
</select>
<select class="tasks">
  <option></option>
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
  <option>baz</option>
  <option>buzz</option>
</select>
<select class="tasks">
  <option></option>
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
  <option>baz</option>
  <option>buzz</option>
</select>
<select class="tasks">
  <option></option>
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
  <option>baz</option>
  <option>buzz</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I just realize the function is not working if the first array/select is empty.

Comment: Oh, you're right, change to `firstEmptyIndex !== -1`

Answer (score -1):

```
function validate_task() {
        var error_msg = [];

        if($('#CatTask1ID').val() === ""){
          error_msg.push('1');
        }
        if($('#CatTask2ID').val() === ""){
          error_msg.push('2');
        }
        if($('#CatTask3ID').val() === ""){
          error_msg.push('3');
        }

        //......

        return error_msg;
}

function validate_task_msg() {
      var arr = validate_task()
       if(arr&& arr.length<=0){
          return true;
       }else if(arr.length == 10){//more
          return "Duplicates";
       }else {
         var msg = arr.join(',');
         return "Task "+ msg + " is empty"
       }
}
```